# Filter array of values by their two first characters

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of values and I want to filter it by their two first characters.

Now my values are strings that always start with an identifier of two characters like 01, 02, 03... Thus I'm doing the following:

```
payloads = []
for pay in all_payloads:
    if pay[:2] == '01':
        payloads.append(pay)
```

I know I can do a list comprehension too, but actually what I want to learn if its possible to filter it directly with `numpy`. I thought maybe `np.where()` it's a good option but it's not working for me...

```
cosl = np.where(all_payloads[:2] == '01')
```

Can somebody help me to learn how to do it?

**Sample inputs**

```
['011b009f2e5141cc3c07be7756e0418a9ce6bc3e1ab13e9e1ffc3f0418943e00000000'
 '011c00f51a51411de008be6f0fe541baa256bd85c2be3eb24af13fdbcb833e00000000'
 '031d0086265141240401be873fea414b64e93b4d0a923e0723f33f2c95a63e00000000'
 '011e00e62c5141a3e306be12c2ef4135d44a3c7b0e773eff51fb3f67da883e00000000'
 '021e00e62c5141a3e306be12c2ef4135d44a3c7b0e773eff51fb3f67da883e00000000'
 '011f0035335141f57107be6806f6410664e9bcd088983ee52ef13fb4b48b3e00000000'
 '012000af405141521704be0184fd41d07752bd5eadb13ef0adf33fe4279c3e00000000'
 '032100ae4351415a94fbbdf9e8024296710b3e4417c93fd77efa3f35b1043f00000000'
 '01220015525141c20601be130e06423648f7bc9341a63e6c35fd3f6972943e00000000']
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Include the sample inputs in the question.

Comment: `where` is only as good as the condition. `all_payloads[:2]` is just the first 2 elements of the array.  `where` isn't an iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use functions from `np.char` module for doing this:

```
a = np.array(["01_a", "01_b", "01_c", "02_a", "02_b", "02_c", "03_a", "03_b", "03_c"])
indices = np.where(np.char.startswith(a, "01"))
print(a[indices])
```

Output:

```
['01_a' '01_b' '01_c']
```

Edit:

Output for your added sample input for `'01'` filtering:

```
['011b009f2e5141cc3c07be7756e0418a9ce6bc3e1ab13e9e1ffc3f0418943e00000000'
'011c00f51a51411de008be6f0fe541baa256bd85c2be3eb24af13fdbcb833e00000000'
'011e00e62c5141a3e306be12c2ef4135d44a3c7b0e773eff51fb3f67da883e00000000'
'011f0035335141f57107be6806f6410664e9bcd088983ee52ef13fb4b48b3e00000000'
'012000af405141521704be0184fd41d07752bd5eadb13ef0adf33fe4279c3e00000000'
'01220015525141c20601be130e06423648f7bc9341a63e6c35fd3f6972943e00000000']
```

indices:

```
(array([0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: In my testing `np.char` functions aren't any faster.

Comment: @hpaulj, I never said they were. OP asked for an np solution. Fastest solution imo would still be the list comprehension, which OP is already aware about.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do filtering using the builtin functions. My take on it is:

```
filtered = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('01'), inputs))
```

Comment: @Lleims dude if you were okay with using built-in functions, why not just go with list comprehensions? it's faster.  `filtered = [x for x in inputs if x.startswith('01')]` .  You mentioned in the question that you were specifically looking for a `numpy` solution hence my answer (btw, list comp is faster than the numpy solution too). Cheers!

Comment: @Shubham well pointed out. Also, I agree, your solution makes more sense for the question asked. Well done!

Comment: Ok! This answer for me was easier with my knowledge that's why I checked as correct, but you are right! Even so, thanks to both of you! @Shubham